# binding.pry not works with command bin/dev

Tags: pry, foreman, ruby-on-rails-7

`binding.pry` not works(console input not available) if i start the server with `bin/dev` command. It only works with `bin/rails s` command.
I understand it has something to do with foreman and Procfile.dev, but I don't know how.
Is this a bug or is it supposed to be like this?

Comment: It works but it just other logs are overwriting over it, it's just a visual glitch which I am also interested in how to resolve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With bin/dev, the Procfile.dev file is run with foreman. The pry issue is caused by the CSS and JS watchers:these just listen to changes in your CSS and JS files.

What you can do is remove the `web: unset PORT && bin/rails server` command from your Procfile, so it will only have the CSS and JS watchers and look like this:

```
js: yarn build --watch
css: yarn build:css --watch
```

Now you'll have to open two terminals, one with `bin/rails s` and the other with `foreman start -f Procfile.dev`. This way your pry works in the server terminal as normal and the watchers are watching as normal.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I.e. remove "web: bin/rails server -p 3000" from Procfile.dev and start two servers in parallel; `./bin/dev` in one terminal window and `bundle exec rails server` in another. Now pry works on the rails server.

Answer (score 2):

A popular approach is to use `pry-remote` which is useful in some ways I didn't expect: https://github.com/Mon-Ouie/pry-remote.

`pry-remote` opens a remote terminal, so where you drop your debugger line (`binding.remote_pry` in the case of `pry-remote`), you'll open another terminal and enter the debugging session by calling `pry-remote` in your shell.

I get this is a bit more complicated, I got used to it, and was able to get away from the noise logged by other process with Foreman.

Comment: This works better than nothing, but when your process has multiple pry lines, you have to open it up in the terminal each time. Pretty cumbersome.

Comment: @pixelearth right, there is no doubt about the downsides, not sure what a good long term solution is.

Answer (score 0):

I use rdbg + vscode remote debug and it works fine.

Update Procfile.dev like this to run rdbg with rails server and set a socket file

```
web: rdbg --command --nonstop --open=vscode --sock_path=tmp/sockets/rdbg.socket -- bundle exec bin/rails server
```

Install VSCode Ruby rdbg Debugger, configure launch.json like this

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Attach to rdbg Process",
      "type": "rdbg",
      "request": "attach",
      "debugPort": "${workspaceRoot}/tmp/sockets/rdbg.socket",
    },
  ]
}
```

Now, VSCode will launching with debugger enable while you run bin/dev, or you can run debugger in vscode by F5 anytime

Comment: Awesome, I do know this is not answer to the question, but this option is great!